# R generate mysql select statements

Tags: r, lapply, rmysql

I need to generate complex select statements that change based on an input file each time my script is ran.

I have a list of names that serves as my filter list, and I have a select statement that has been suggested to me in another thread.  I'm not sure how to generate what I need without sitting on google for the next 6 hours piecing it together.

I need to create a MAX(CASE... line for each item in the list.

```
list <- df$names

list:
1  square
2  ball
3  dog
4  triangle
5  hamster
6  circle
7  yellow
8  cat

suggested SELECT format:
SELECT 
   data.loc
 , data.type
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'hamster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hamster
FROM 
 data
GROUP BY 
   data.loc
 , data.type
```

I believe the desired output would be:

```
SELECT 
   data.loc
 , data.type
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'square' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS square
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'ball' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ball
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'dog' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dog
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'triangle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS triangle
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'hamster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hamster
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'circle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS circle
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yellow
, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat
FROM 
 data
GROUP BY 
   data.loc
 , data.type
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach that I could think of is

```
l <- list("Cat", "dog", "bird")
sqlqry <- "SELECT 
   data.loc
 , data.type"
for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  sqlqry <- paste0(sqlqry, sprintf(", MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = '%s' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS %s",l[i], l[i]))
  print(sqlqry)
}
sqlqry <- paste0(sqlry, "your where clause")
```